# Pushing a local git repo to Overleaf produces an error about submodules but the repo has no submodules

Tags: git

I followed the instruction on Overleaf to push a local repository to a blank project on overleaf v2 ([as detailed on their website](https://de.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/How_do_I_push_a_new_project_to_Overleaf_via_git%3F)).

Pulling from the overleaf repository works fine. But pushing to it produces an error about submodules but the local repo has no submodules.

```
> git push overleaf master
  
remote: error: invalid git repo
remote: 
remote: hint: Your Git repository contains a reference we cannot resolve.
remote: hint: If your project contains a Git submodule,
remote: hint: please remove it and try again.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit to respond to comment***

The output of `git remote -v` shows the repository that is on overleaf, I replaced the id by 'xxxxx' here:

```
JanaJarecki     https://github.com/JanaJarecki/my-correct-repo.git (fetch)
JanaJarecki     https://github.com/JanaJarecki/my-correct-repo.git (push)
overleaf        https://git.overleaf.com/xxxxx (fetch)
overleaf        https://git.overleaf.com/xxxxx (push)
my-collaborator        https://github.com/my-collaborator/correct-repo.git (fetch)
my-collaborator        https://github.com/my-collaborator/correct-repo.git (push)
```

Comment: What is the output of `git remote -v`?

Comment: just a note: the error is about _references_ not _submodules_. The most common source of missing references is submodules, but this might not be the case.

Comment: @sergej: thank you, I added the output in the post. Anything weird that I am missing?

Comment: @DaemonPainter Right, it's just that the submodule is the most common issue according to the web so I needed to make clear that my prior is low that this is the issue.

Comment: I'm having the same issue - @JBJ did you figure this out?

Comment: No I didn't, I think I reinitialized everything back in the days